# Magento custom price value not converting by changing currency

Tags: php, magento, cart, price

**Following code is used to set custom price for simple product. Custom price set in cart as needed but when i switch currency then custom price value remains same with current currency symbol.**

```
 $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Is there any way to set custom price that work with currency switching.

Comment: Similar issue is still remain on Magento 2.3 & Magento 2.4. I fixed it by creating this patches: https://github.com/araujophillips/magento2-issue-33134/tree/master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to do this.

**First Step:**

Add item to quote with custom price using following code suggested by @Ashish Raj

```
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$price = $customPrice;

$customPrice = $Current_currency_price = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);

$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

**Second Step:**

Second step is to create an controller post dispatch observer by adding following code in config.xml file of module

```
<events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers>
                <frontend_currency_change>
                    <class>modulename/observer</class>
                    <method>hookToControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
                </frontend_currency_change>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
    </events>
```

And add following code to observer class

```
    public function hookToControllerActionPostDispatch($observer) {
            if ($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'directory_currency_switch') {
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                if ($quote && $quote->hasItems()) {
                    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item):
                        //add condition for target item
                        $customPrice = 23;//use custom price logic
                        $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
                        $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
                        $customPrice = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($customPrice, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
                    endforeach;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is working for me. Hope this will help to someone having same issue.
I will prefer if somebody have better solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code hope it will help you ...

**First Step:**

```
//you need to find base currency code and then find current currency code...
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$price = $customPrice;
```

**Second Step:**

```
//convert price from base currency to current currency
$customPrice = $Current_currency_price = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);
```

**3rd Step:**

then you can use your code:

```
$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But i am not facing issue with current currency. I have added item in cart with custom price which is fine. Now if i switch currency on cart page then price value remains unchanged for that item.

Comment: Hi @gulshan maurya , did you find the resolution on above task? let me know here please

Comment: I didn't found any solution yet, related task is on hold for now. I will update here if i will get any better solution.

Comment: Hi @AshishRaj, is that worked for you? I tried but not working.